# How can I wait on multiple processes across users?

Tags: c++, windows, synchronization

I have some code in process A that needs to wait until work completes in other processes that can be running simultaneously under multiple users.

I'm uncertain what is the appropriate synchronization mechanism. I naively thought a global named semaphore would be the answer but semaphores are signaled once anyone releases them, and I would want to wait until all clients release them, or a timeout occurs.

**Question**: Is there an appropriate synchronization mechanism for this scenario?

Comment: Which programming language?  In C# you would use [`Task.WaitAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx), though I suppose that won't work if you're waiting on *processes.*  For that, you would do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27680977/102937).  See also [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wait+on+all+processes+to+complete).

Comment: I'm not waiting for the process to complete; I'm waiting for work *within* the process to complete.

Comment: No, you're waiting on processes to complete.  How else are you going to get a signal from each process if you can't get a return value?

Comment: Plenty of ways - global named semaphores, global named events, named pipes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a named pipe and waiting for confirmation messages from the `n` processes should work (i.e. the supervisor waits for `n` messages on the pipe). This would have the advantage of also allowing a complex result to be posted instead of just a notification, should this be required.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility (as long as you don't have a *huge* number of tasks) is to have an array of Events, one for each task.

Each child process can set its associated Event when it finishes its task. The parent uses WaitForMultipleObjects (passing `true` for the `bWaitAll` parameter) to wait until they're all finished.

Comment: This is a solid idea but I don't know the number of tasks ahead of time so quantity is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like multi reader single writer pattern.  I believe that you need a semaphore and a mutex (or two) to make this work correctly.

Comment: And they will need to be in the global namespace to handle multiple user's.